# How to get full URL in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, puppeteer

I have a url `https://twitter.com/Javeria85685955/status/1059335612346650624`
I want to get full url in Node.js on runtime. I am using `puppeteer` scraping.

**My Code is**:

```
const url = require('url');
const myURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
console.log('This is a full URL: ' + JSON.stringify(myURL))
```

**It gives me output like**:

This is a full URL:

```
{
    "protocol": null,
    "slashes": null,
    "auth": null,
    "host": null,
    "port": null,
    "hostname": null,
    "hash": null,
    "search": null,
    "query": {},
    "pathname": "/",
    "path": "/",
    "href": "/"
}
```

**But Required Output I need**:

https://twitter.com/Javeria85685955/status/1059335612346650624

Comment: What is `req.url`? The output suggests it is blank. I have no idea how you expect a computer to be able to go from "nothing" to a URL on twitter.com.

Comment: Are you a twitter developer?

Comment: it is coming from callback function

Comment: i am nodejs developer.

Comment: i want to fetch url on runtime.I am using puppeteer nodejs module.

Comment: What is the code you are using for puppeteer? And what is the output of `req.url`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `puppeteer` then why aren't you taking advantage of the `puppeteer` API to retrieve your URL as follows:

```
const url = await page.url();
console.log(url); // This will output the current URL to the console
```

Seems like the simplest solution to me?

Comment: This games me only base url.  In example "example.com" as opposed to example.com/thisismy.html . @AJC24

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const myURL = req.headers.referer;
```

Comment: It return the same result as previous

Comment: try to get hostname form req.headers.host and URL from req.url